# Gamma ray bursts luminosity measurement

Tags: astronomy, observational-astronomy, gamma-rays

physicists use millisecond fluxes i.e.,fluxes calculated within  a very short timescale to measure the actual 1 second flux for these  grbs.But to do that they have to multiply the millisecond fluxes by a factor of 10^3. So why instead of recording and using the actual 1 second peak flux as received by the detectors  they use millisecond fluxes to convert them to 1 sec fluxes from which later they can derive the luminosity?  IN case of other such high energy astrophysical phenomenas which include blazars physicists use photon flux/second, but not in case of GRBs.So isn't there a chance that the luminosity derived from such millisecond fluxes might be affected with some errors?

Comment: There are two types of GRBs: short duration and long long duration. Short ones last for about a second while the long ones might last up to 10 seconds. It is then necessary to use sub-second measurements to get a flux.

Comment: But for all types of bursts whether long or short physicists use millisecond fluxes (in short time bins of 64,256 and 16) before converting them to 1 sec lonng peak luminosity. Anyone can search that by typing a burst name and then Konus Wind observations.(e.g, grb 110918a konus wind observation) I.don't know whether the method is used to address the short variabilities which arise even in 2+ sec long Grbs